# How to re-enable disabled right click menu in browser?

Tags: browser, javascript, context-menu, right-click

I am used to using the right click menu to navigate webpage, which allows me to go backward or forward on a page without moving the cursor to the navigation bar. I mostly use Firefox.

But some websites think that they can prevent image piracy by blocking the right click menu. This is annoying, especially for those that pops up a window.

I know I can disable Javascript but I need to reload the page to make it effective and often times it cause the page to not render properly. Is there a generic way to fix that? Say, using the Web Developer menu?

Comment: Yes;  The generic method is to block the javascript responsible for the behavior.

Comment: This is surely a duplicate many times over.